# Fetch Azure blob metadata only if the blob exists

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to fetch the metadata for an Azure blob if it exists and would like to achieve this with minimal REST calls (by the storage SDK to the storage service)

I know I can do something like

- `CloudBlockBlob.ExistsAsync()` and then
- `CloudBlockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync()` if the blob exists

I tried to combine these 2 calls into one

- `CloudBlockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync(AccessCondition.GenerateIfExistsCondition(),new BlobRequestOptions(), new OperationContext());`

Docs on '[AccessCondition.GenerateIfExistsCondition()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.accesscondition.generateifexistscondition?view=azure-dotnet)' say -

> Constructs an access condition such that an operation will be
>   performed only if the resource exists.

but it still fails with a 404 not found.

Any idea if what I want to achieve is even possible and what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for the action: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties.

It's basically a HEAD request to the blob, and there is no mention of If-Match etc. for headers.

So I think the most optimal way of doing it is just calling FetchAttributesAsync.
If that causes a 404, then the blob did not exist.
It only does 1 HTTP request.

Comment: Would need to wrap it in a try catch. Wanted to avoid generating exceptions as far as possible 

Comment: Right, that would indeed be nice. If you could tell the Storage SDK to not throw, but return null if not found etc..

Comment: I did check the decomiled code. It adds the if-match header with a value of '*'. Don't know how that's processed by the server though

Comment: The AccessCondition can be specified so you can specify a *lease id* if you have acquired a lease on the blob.